# file_get_contents php and json_decode error

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents, json

I am facing a weird problem with **file_get_contents** and decoding to json the result. I have to tell you that this code was fully functional in other server.

I am trying to decode this json: 
http://mediarupt.com/GET/categorized_services_for_supplier.php?suppliersID=10

into this page: 
http://mediarupt.com/kostas.php

The code for kostas.php is this:

```
<?php 
$servicesJSON = file_get_contents("http://mediarupt.com/GET/categorized_services_for_supplier.php?suppliersID=10");
$ForeignKeys = (object)array();
$ForeignKeys->ServicesList = json_decode($servicesJSON, true);

echo "error: " . json_last_error();

?>

<select name="servicesID" id="servicesID">
    <option id="serviceID_0" value="0" rel="0" style="font-style:italic;">Select a category...</option>
<?php foreach($ForeignKeys->ServicesList['categorized_services'] as $value){ ?>
    <option id="serviceID_<?=$value['servicesID']?>" value="<?=$value['servicesID']?>" rel="<?=$value['hasStoresList']?>"><?=$value['serviceName']?></option>   

<?php } ?>

</select>
<?php

echo '<br><br>The result of file_get_contents ($servicesJSON): '.$servicesJSON;

?>
```

Code for categorized_services_for_supplier.php:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require('../settings/dbli.php');

    $table = array();
    $suppliersID = "0";

    if(isset($_GET['suppliersID']) && $_GET['suppliersID']!=NULL && $_GET['suppliersID']!='' ){  $suppliersID = $SQLConn->real_escape_string($_GET['suppliersID']); }
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Services.servicesID, serviceName, servicePrice, hasStoresList FROM Services, ServicesList WHERE Services.servicesID = ServicesList.servicesID AND suppliersID = '$suppliersID' AND  status = '1' AND deleted = '0'";

    $result = $SQLConn->query($query);  
     while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $tempArray = array();
        foreach($row as $key => $value){
            $tempArray[$key] = $value;                      
        }
        array_push($table,$tempArray);
     }
     $arr = array( "categorized_services" => $table);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

I receive error **4** as latest json error, which means that I have **JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX**.
But I validate the json result with http://jsonlint.com/ and all seems to be ok.

Also, both pages are UTF-8 with BOM disabled.
You can access php configurarion here: http://mediarupt.com/phpinfo.php

I hope to find the solution...

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have done a test output of `echo $servicesJSON;` and it contains the JSON code?

Comment: yes of course, I just changed my code to see the result of echo $servicesJSON

Comment: You say you've validated with jsonlint.com, but pasting your url there and validating indicates the json isn't valid.

Comment: yes indeed, but just copy and paste the pure string (the result of categorized_services_for_supplier.php)...You will see that there is no error there..

Comment: Copy pasting the string obviously removes whatever character is causing the string to be invalid in the response, the response is still invalid.

Comment: The weird part here is that exactly the same pages on other server run with no problem...

Comment: Total shot in the dark: try `$servicesJSON = trim($servicesJSON)` before decoding

Comment: Still dark :P @Pekka웃

Comment: I copy at the body of question the code of categorized_services_for_supplier.php page...please check it if you can see any problem there...Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The json is simply invalid.

In front of the first opening curly braces there is the following content (hex encoded) `ef bb bf ef bb bf`

It is the utf8 bom.

There is a question related to deal with exactly that, so I will not cover it here. Read up here:

[How to remove %EF%BB%BF in a PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057742/how-to-remove-efbbbf-in-php-string)

and another one dealing specifically with json here:

[Convert UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 with no BOM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

Try to give `JSON URL` in the http://jsonlint.com/ and than copy the response and paste it in a file with `BOM` disabled you will notice that there is a strange small line in the beginning before the opening `{` bracket which is causing the issues

Comment: You need to find out why is that small strange line coming and you need to remove it. Hope that helps

Comment: I have noticed that indeed, I copy the code of the page at the body of my question... I ll try to rewrite the script from scratch in new page