# Redirect to another site Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, redirect

I need to redirect to a page that i get from my DB, but, i need to do this in my controller.

Is there any way to redirect to another page using some angular function?

Because `$locate` and `window.location` just put the link after my website base url.
Here an example of what it is doing now:

`http://ip/cliente_ecommerce_v2/em_desenvolvimento/front/bernardo/%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BFhttps://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html?code=nope`

The code:

```
Conecta('get','getFinalizaCompra', Cookies.get("hash_cliente")).then(function(valor) {
            console.log(valor);
           window.location.href = valor;
        });
```

Comment: The server is returning a bad string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057742/how-to-remove-efbbbf-in-a-php-string

Comment: Worked, thank you. Post as a answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just put `$data = substr($data, 9);` in the response of my curl . This makes the garbage that came along with the link is ignored and the link began to function normally. This code causes the 9 first letters of the string are ignored by php.