# Change encoding of a file to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php

I need to convert a CSV file from `UCS-2LE` to `UTF-8` encoding. So far I've tried the following:

```php
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE'); 
file_put_contents($newfile, $str);
```

But the problem is PHP encoding the new file as `UTF-8 BOM` instead of pure `UTF-8` (according to Notepad++).

[image]

Notepad++ also have options to set encoding as `UTF-8` (without the BOM).

[image]

I don't understand why PHP adding `BOM` on `UTF-8` even when I explicitly instructed it to `UTF-8` only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove %EF%BB%BF in a PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057742/how-to-remove-efbbbf-in-a-php-string)

Comment: It somewhat does but does not seem to be perfect answer.

Comment: well, (opinion) stripping BOMs is quite imperfect :)

Comment: Both `mb_convert_encoding()` and `iconv()` seem to add a BOM when converting to UTF-8 and I'm not aware of a way to control that. You'll probably need to strip it yourself.